# Email Application Question

Tags: asp.net

I have created some webforms that will allow users to fill in their data.  Afterwards, the information is processed and inserted into a database with a follow up email to me afterwards letting me know who signed up.

The problem is that I use different email addresses on all of these webforms.

What I would like is some sort of dashboard email application where I can view all the emails being sent to me from one central point.

I think that Thunderbird allows you to receive multiple emails from different accounts.  Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Why are you using different email addresses?

Comment: I ask, because if you're doing it merely to classify the emails by the initiating webform, there's an easier way than using multiple accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure just about any email application to receive mail from multiple accounts.  Thunderbird does this as does outlook (not outlook express).  Just go through the normal process you do to add an account, then go ahead and add another account under a different email address.

Here's a link to a walk through on how to do this on [Thunderbird](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_create_multiple_accounts_in_mozilla_thunderbird.html).